# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure in Visual Studio 2022 for .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, iis-express

My .NET Core 3.1 Razor page application is working fine in VS 2019, but when I am trying to run same application in newly installed VS2022 17.8, I am getting below error. While installing VS2022 I had already selected .NET Core 3.1.

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

- I have done few settings as per these suggestions but nothing worked out.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18262

https://itecnote.com/tecnote/asp-net-core-net-core-3-1-http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure/

https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-fix-ancm-in-process-start-failure-asp-net-core/

- I installed .NET Core 3.1 SDK and Hosting Bundle from following location, but it didn't work.
  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1
- I tried to create a new .NET Core 3.1 razor page application that also giving same error.
- When I created .NET Core 2.1, 6.0, 8.0 .NET core razor page application, it's all working fine, only getting error in 3.1.
- I tried to run that application in Visual Studio 2022 17.3.4 on different machine and it works fine.
- I also reinstalled Visual Studio 2022 17.8.1 but having same issue.

Error screenshot attached:

[image]

Installer settings:

[image]

Comment: This matches the meaning of “out of support”, so not worth any further discussion.

Comment: I believe you can refer to this blog https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-fix-ancm-in-process-start-failure-asp-net-core/.

Comment: Hi @ramya, does your application run with IIS Express or hosting on any server? Could you pls check the Output panel in visual studio if any detailed exception here?